# Limit of sequence given by $a_n = \frac{1}{3}(a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} + a_{n-3})$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

I have the sequence modeled by the equation $$a_n = \dfrac{1}{3}(a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} + a_{n-3}), \:a_1 = 1,\: a_2 = 2,\: a_3 = 3.$$ Simply by manually calculating the sequence I know it converges around $2.3$, but I do not know how to express it in terms of a limit. Since it relies on the previous $3$ values of the sequence I do not know how to express this formulaically.

Comment: I kind of doubt that since if it really converges, you can calculate the limit out by setting $9a^2=1$, which clearly isn't 2.3 you get.

Comment: Hint: If $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=l$ then what happens when you take limit on both sides?

Comment: There is a very standard way of solving linear recurrence relation. In this case, if $\alpha_k$'s are zeros of $3x^3-x^2-x-1=0$, then $$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{3}c_k \alpha_k^n$$ for some constants $c_k$'s, which can be determined by the initial values.

Comment: @SangchulLee And one of $\alpha_k=1$ in this problem.

Comment: @YadatiKiran I'm not sure it will help here because all you will get is $l=\frac{1}{3}[l+l+l]=l$.

Comment: @AnuragA: Initially the problem was $a_n = \dfrac{1}{3(a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} + a_{n-3})}$. I guess the OP has edited the post.

Answer (score 5):

You will find that the limit is $\frac16 a_1 + \frac13 a_2 + \frac12 a_3$

which with $a_1 = 1,\: a_2 = 2,\: a_3 = 3$ gives a limit of $\frac73 \approx 2.3333$

More generally, if $a_n$ is the average of the previous $k$ terms then the limit is $$\frac{2}{k(k+1)}(a_1+2a_2+3a_3+\ldots + ka_k)$$

Answer (score 5):

Let 
$$b_n=a_n+\dfrac23 a_{n-1}+\dfrac 13 a_{n-2},\tag{*}$$
we have
$$b_n=b_{n-1},\qquad b_3=a_3+\dfrac23 a_{2}+\dfrac 13 a_{1}=\frac{14}3.$$
Obviously $b_n$ converges to $b_3=\frac{14}3$. If $a_n$ has a limit $l$, by taking limits on both sides of $(*)$,
$$\frac{14}3=l+\frac 23 l+\frac 13 l\implies l=\frac 73.$$

Comment: If I may ask, how did you come up with general term $b_n$?